# how to jquery append only one time if i have two hosts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have dinamically crated page that fetch db data and print it on page. Project stored on claster contains two hosts. If i use `append()` method it dublicate data, because each host make `append()` call. So my question is how to make append only one time if two hosts run directly at the same time? For example i do

```
var arr = ["NY", "LA", "CA", "ETC"]
for (var i in arr){
    $('#container').append(arr[i])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function onlyUnique(value, index, self) { 
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

// usage example:
var arr = ["NY", "LA", "CA", "ETC","NY"];
var unique = arr.filter( onlyUnique ); 

console.log(unique);
```

you can try the following before appending data

Comment: im so stupid, but your answer made me think about task that helped me find correct way to check if element already exists. Thank you